# How to filter out NaN?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I write out the sum in a `<div>`, but before I put in values in my input-boxes it shows `NaN`.
How do I filter it out to avoid Nan ?

**app.js**

```
$(document).ready(calculate);   
$(document).on("keyup", calculate);

function calculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    var value1 = $("#a_price").val();
    var value2 = $("#otherElemenet").val();
    $(".o-money__answer").each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat(monetary_factor.replace(",", ".")) * parseFloat($(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val());
    });
    $("#o-money__totalsum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

**PHP**

```
<form class="o-money__form" id="<?php echo $counter; ?>" method="post" action="#">
    <?php $rows = get_field('pengar'); ?>
    <?php if ($rows): ?>
        <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
            <div class="o-money__positionInput">
            <div class="right50">
            <label class="label labelInput">Antal <?php echo $row['typ_av_enhet']; ?></label> 
            </div>
            <input type="text" value="" class="o-money__answer">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['a_price'];?>">
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <label id="o-money__totalsum"> 0</label>
        </form>
        <!--
        <?php
            if(have_rows('pengar')):
                while(have_rows('pengar')) :
                    the_row();
                    $a_price = get_sub_field('a_price');
                    $monetary_factor = get_field('monetary_factor', 'option');
        ?>
        -->
        <?php
                    break;
                endwhile;
            endif;
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

[See picture of what im trying to demonstrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYexj.png)

Comment: You need to post enough code that we can copy it to our own machines and reproduce your problem. Best to create a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net, but if you don't want to do that, at least post a working sample in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for NaN using `isNaN`:

```
if(!isNaN(sum))$("#o-money__totalsum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a javascript native method called `isNaN()`.

You just need to test it before displaying anything.

```
if (isNaN(your_var)) {
    ....
} else {
    ....
}
```